# cannot open file irvine32.inc

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I am trying to assemble program in masm 6.15, but it gives the error as mentioned in title. I am trying to search this error in Google and different search engine, but no helpful information is available, so kindly help.

Comment: Do you own the book "Assembly Language for Intel-Based Computers"? That is the source of the include file. http://www.amazon.com/Assembly-Language-Intel-Based-Computers-5th/dp/0132383101

Answer (score 3):

Try writing the absolute path to file. And perhaps try including irnive32.lib using the

```
includelib irvine32.lib
```

I used that same library and read the book. I avoided visual studio and used the MASM32 assembler and the editor that came with it. I did not have any problem with include files since!

Comment: thanks
And can you tell me about what is difference between masm and masm32.

Comment: The difference is that "MASM32" is a stand alone assembler and is not part of the Visual Studio. It comes with complete Windows standard library and an editor.

Answer (score 2):

open project properties.
expand Microsoft Macro assembly << click on general.
add folder path in "**INCLUDE PATHS**".[image]